# Padding added in sidebar, not coming from my style sheet

Tags: css

Space is being added to a sidebar in a WordPress theme I have created. The space isn't being added via my own style sheet, but I think I have isolated it to this from my code editor:

```
    ul, menu, dir {
      display: block;
      list-style-type: disc;
      -webkit-margin-before: 1em;
      -webkit-margin-after: 1em;
      -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
      -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
      -webkit-padding-start: 40px;
    }
```

I've attached a couple of pictures showing the site as it appears normally, and with the code editor's highlighting of the space.

The weird thing is that the "-webkit-margin-*" styles are locked in my code inspector so I cannot edit them. Trying to add the same values to my theme's style sheet with the 1em margins swapped for zeroes doesn't seem to have any effect.

Has anyone dealt with this before?

[image: Sidebar]

[image: Sidebar with space highlighted]

**EDIT**

As discussed in the comments, the problem wasn't with padding/margins but with a header tag which contained nothing but a single space (hence the following items started on a newline, which looked a lot like 1em padding).

The header tag is generated by the register_sideber() function in widgets.php:

```
    function register_sidebar($args = array()) {
        global $wp_registered_sidebars;

        $i = count($wp_registered_sidebars) + 1;

        $defaults = array(
                'name' => sprintf(__('Sidebar %d'), $i ),
                'id' => "sidebar-$i",
                'description' => '',
                'class' => '',
                'before_widget' => '<li id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
                'after_widget' => "</li>\n",
                'before_title' => '<h2 class="widgettitle">',
                'after_title' => "</h2>\n",
        );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are seeing a browser default.  Most browsers have some styles built in by default which unfortunately often include margins and padding.  A lot of developers will put a basic reset on the top of their CSS file, something like

```
*{margin:0;padding:0;border:none}
```

This will clear the defaults and only display margins/paddings/borders that you explicitly define.

If you only want to remove the space from that one element, try adding something like this to your stylesheet:

```
#sidebar{margin:0;padding:0}
```

This isn't so much a wordpress thing as it is a general CSS thing to be aware of.

Comment: That's not it, but I have found the problem. Towards the top of my sidebar div there's this:

`<li id="pages-3" class="widget widget_pages"><h2 class="widgettitle"> </h2>`

The h2 is causing the space, but it looked liked margin/padding due to containing nothing but a space character.

Now to work out if the widgettitle h2 is being generated by register_sidebar(), dynamic_sidebar(), or from somewhere within the widget's code...

Answer (score 0):

It's probably the widget code that prints the h2 tag even if it has not value.

Try searching for the code in the sidebar.php and see where it generates those tags. Most of the time, these widget codes are generated in a theme-basis and not the widgets.

Comment: It was in widgets.php. I've edited my question with more details.